# What is "Flatten" doing to my elements?

Tags: list-manipulation

Here's some of my code. x1 results in returning the position of a list in a {{{n1}},{{n2}}...}. Im trying to flatten it such that the list reads out as {n1,n2,n3....} some how it's adding elements.
Length of x1 is 428, Length of x2 is 438. What's going on here and more importantly what can I do to have a 1 dimensional list?

```
x1 = Table[Position[guessSpec[[;; , n]], MaxSig[[n]]], {n, WLRegion}]
x2 = Flatten[Table[Position[guessSpec[[;; , n]], MaxSig[[n]]], {n, WLRegion}]]
```

ArrayReshape doesn't seem to work either

Edit:guessSpec is something like {{1,2,3,4,5...},{{1,2,3,4,5...},....},
MaxSig is {1,2,3,4......},
WLRegion is a constant (500)

Comment: Please include all variable definitions so your code can be tested.

Comment: I suspect a simplified example of your data is: `l1 = Table[Position[{1,2,2,2,3}, n], {n, 3}]` where the result is `{{{1}},{{2},{3},{4}},{{5}}}`, and `l2 = Flatten[l1]` is `{1,2,3,4,5}`, so `Length/@{l1, l2}` is `{3, 5}`. Notice that $l2$ is longer than $l1$.